# How to repair a chipped granite countertop

Tags: kitchen-counters, granite, chip

We've recently moved into a house and the previous owner was rough on the granite countertop around the kitchen sink:

The edge:

[image]

The corner:

[image]

I've been advised that if I use epoxy it will yellow (the sink is right under a southern exposure window) and so I'd like to use a Dremel 3000 to smooth out the rough edges around the sink and the corner of the sink as well.

Can you recommend:

1. A set of Dremel diamond burr bits
2. A respirator face mask to use

Once I get a set of bits, which bit would work best for smoothing out the edges? What recommendations do you have as to how to make the edges and corner smooth with the right bit?

I understand that granite has a lot of quartz in it and the dust particles are sharp. I'll be wearing goggles, leather gloves, a long sleeve shirt, and of course a mask. Any other precautions?

Thanks,

David Watson

Comment: One option might be to find a larger sink that will allow the damaged areas to be cut out.  Another option might be to have the surface ground down to remove the damage.  But neither is really a DIY job.

Comment: "The best" in what regard? In terms of lowest cost? Highest quality (what defines quality - finish, lifespan, something else)? "The best" is too broad and opinion based to be answered objectively.

Comment: Now this becomes a product recommendation/review question which is also off topic.

Comment: Jwh20 (or anyone else), do you think this job could be done with a Dremel stone carving set that includes Diamond Burr Accessories? There are several on the market that  can carve granite and don't wear out quickly.